# MFC (Windows Mobile). How to create a radio button with custom images and labels for checked and unchecked state?

Tags: mfc, radio-button, windows-mobile, cbutton

I tried to create a custom button class and use it. But it works for CBitmapButton class only.
Is it possible with subclassing of radio button?
My current temporary solution is to extend my custom button class by adding the radio button functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a solution so I have created a button which look likes a radio button